# How to remove continue shopping button from woo commerce cart?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to remove the continue shopping button from the woo commerce cart if the cart contains all the products. It's not removing the button so just need help in fine tuning what I am doing incorrectly. I thought my code will work and my php debugger is not working at the moment for some strange reason.

The element for the continue shopping button is: `name="hpy_cs_continue"`

Here is the code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart', 'verify_all_products_in_cart' );
    
function verify_all_products_in_cart() {
    
    $all_products = false;
    $all_products_array  = wc_get_products( array( 'return' => 'ids', 'limit' => -1 ) );
    $products_in_cart_array = array();
    
  // Loop over $cart items
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {    
    $products_in_cart_array &= in_array($cart_item['product_id']);
}
    if($all_products_array == $products_in_cart_array){
        $all_products = true;
    } else{
        $all_products = false;
    }
                                  
  if ($all_products = true){
      $shopping_cart_button = '<style>[name="hpy_cs_continue"]{ display:none;}</style>';
  } else{
      $shopping_cart_button = '<style>[name="hpy_cs_continue"]{ display:block;}</style>';
  }
   
    return $shopping_cart_button;
  
}
```

Comment: You may see this article. it will helps you. [Removing Continue Shopping button from Added to Cart Notice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49058914/removing-continue-shopping-button-from-added-to-cart-notice)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, your [in_array()](https://www.php.net/in_array) requires 2 parameter; your code has one.

If you're developing, I'd recommend adding `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` to your wp-config.php file to catch things like that.  As part of your debug process, if your `<style>` blocks are always rendering `display: block;`, it should indicate that your if statement is always yielding false.

I would also recommend using if `( ! array_diff(...) )` instead of looping through the arrays, or if must loop through them.  Actually, I'm not sure how comparing 2 arrays like that would behave, but even if you just changed that, I would recommend if ( count(...) === count(...) ).

Hopefully this helped.